# Custom Post Types not showing correct archive template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, mod-rewrite, custom-post-type

I have a few custom post types on my site:

- lydbok
- live
- bidragsyter

[The post types are set up using this code.](http://pastebin.com/r3KnDY9J)

The *lydbok* post type have been working good on it's on. But when I created the other custom post types I ran into a problem when creating the archive-{post-type}.php templates. It seems that WordPress is using archive-lydbok.php even though I've added the archive templates for the other post types as well.

I now have these archive-templates in my themes folder(all files with just the file name inside, no code):

- archive-lydbok.php
- archive-live.php
- archive-bidragsyter.php
- archive.php

But when I visit *mysite.com/?post_type=live* or *mysite.com/?post_type=bidragsyter* WordPress is showing the archive-lydbok.php template instead of their respective templates. If i delete archive-lydbok.php the same URLs are showing the archive.php file. Not their archive-{post-type}.php template.

I have tried updating the permalinks inside of WordPress admin, as well as deleting the .htaccess and flushing rewrites using flush_rewrite_rules(); — but I'm still experiencing the same result.

It's worth mentioning that I created the *lydbok* post type using [Pods](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pods/) a few months earlier, but deleted the plugin to use PHP code instead. Not sure if that have anything to do with it? The Pods plugin is completly removed.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me on several occasions, but mostly its solved by permalink update. Once i also had to rename a custom post type to make it work.

Try removing the lydbok post type code from your functions. And see if the rest of the post types follow the their corresponding archive page. If it works then you should rename your custom post type "lydbok" to something else.

Comment: After removing the *lydbok* post type I still get the archive-lydbok.php template on the URL /?post_type=live, and a PHP notice of *"Trying to get property of non-object in /home/simen/joss_dev_sites/ferdigsnakkav2/web/wp/wp-includes/template.php on line 116"*. When I rename the *lydbok* post type I get the same result. After renaming the post type, the URL /?post_type=lydbok gives me the front-page.php template.

Comment: I tried setting up a fresh WordPress install using the same theme(but no plugins installed), and I still get the same issues. Still only showing archive-lydbok.php for all custom post types.

Comment: Try changing the order the custom post types are loaded in.  make lydbok the last post type to be registered. OR use the plugin "CUSTOM POST TYPE UI" to create the post types

Comment: Same result using Custom Post Type UI. My guess is that there's something up with my theme. I'm using a customized version of the Roots  starter theme(Gromf). Anyway. I guess I'll just have to use a workaround, using a page and page-{page-slug}.php template. Cause that works. Thanks for your help omer.